# How to check if a list is empty in this specific response format with null object in Android

Tags: android, json, list, api, null

I got a response back from the API like this below:

```
{
    "transactions": [null]
}
```

However, when I tried to debug, List.getTransactionItems().size() is equal 1 rather than 0. I think it considers null as an item. Also, I checked few things as below but none of them work.

```
if (this.transactionsViewModel.getTransactionItems().size() == 0
                || this.transactionsViewModel.getTransactionItems() == null
                || this.transactionsViewModel.getTransactionItems().isEmpty()
                || this.transactionsViewModel.getTransactionItems().equals(null))
```

However, when I tried to call something like that below, it actually recognized that there is an null item in the list.

```
this.transactionsViewModel.getTransactionItems().contains(null)
```

Any idea in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should edit the server code for response `"transactions": []` not `"transactions": [null]`

Comment: Yeah that's probably the easiest solution. But if the client doesn't want to change the response, how can I handle it on the app?

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to add value from `json` to `transactionItems`

Comment: it is using gson lib. So basically I cannot use isNull() to check it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, json array not supposed to be null like that. You can make `"transactions": []` or `"transactions": null` instead. That behaviour happens because your code recognise that the array is not empty. It has 1 item with null value.

Comment: Yeah I knew it. But we are working with client and there is a high chance that they not gonna change it. First time seeing something like [null] for an empty List btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not change the server response.
You can check if the list only contains null by removeAll null object from your list then check the size

```
(this.transactionsViewModel.getTransactionItems().removeAll(Collections.singleton(null))).size() == 0
// size == 0 your list only contains null
// size > 0  your list is not empty
```

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the stream into a string, and doing a search and replace on the json string, and remove the null, before you parse the json? You can also extend a stream class, and do it in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem about the unsuitable response from the server. To solve your problem, you can only to make **some workaround** in your code.

I suggest you should keep your application as clear and origin as possible. Don't change the condition call if it is really necessary.

The following is my suggested code ( used some code from Phan Van Linh)

This class used Retrofit library as the example to make the callback abstract

```
public class TestFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testlayout, null, false);
        RestA rest = UtilRetrofit.build(RestA.class);//from the restful endpoint
        Call<YourObject> call = rest.getTransactions();
        call.enqueue(new TransactionCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(YourObject bean) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Hello World", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<YourObject> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public abstract class TransactionCallback implements Callback<YourObject> {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<YourObject> call, Response<YourObject> response) {
            YourObject lNewBean = response.body();
            lNewBean.getTransactions().removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));// do some custom action and remove useless thing
            onResponse(lNewBean);
        }
        public abstract void onResponse(YourObject bean);
    }
    /**
     * Created by me on 22/8/2016.
     */
    public static class YourObject {
        private List<String> transactions;
        public List<String> getTransactions() {
            return transactions;
        }
        public void setTransactions(List<String> pTransactions) {
            transactions = pTransactions;
        }
    }
}
```